# Can I start a sentence with "Besides" just followed by a comma?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I think I need something after "Besides", like in "Besides this fact,....". But I am not so sure.

I also have the same question with "Beside" (without ending 's').

Comment: J.R. explained the "confusion about the two words beside and besides" once for me. I believe that it'd be useful for you too: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13618/3281.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The true sticklers for grammar will say no, because "besides" is a conjunction (or I guess more specifically a conjunctive adverb), and many believe that the rule is that sentences shouldn't begin with conjunctions.

However, colloquially, beginning a sentence with "besides" makes perfect sense: "He didn't go to the store because he was tired. Besides, it was raining." I would usually say "*And* besides, it was raining", but I think that is just a personal preference.

You can also begin a sentence with "beside", but it has a different meaning. "Beside" is a preposition of direction: "Beside the store was a toxic waste dump."

You can always say "beside that", which is basically a synonym for "besides". Joining the relative pronoun "that" with the preposition of direction "beside" makes a phrase that pretty much functions like the conjunctive adverb "besides": "He didn't go to the store because it was raining. And beside that, there was a toxic waste dump next door."

TL;DR: Yes to your first question, and yes to your second question (though the meaning is different).

Comment: Are there *any* serious style guides that actually defend the "rule" that sentences shouldn't begin with conjunctions?

Comment: [Nope](http://centrediting.com.au/2013/06/17/mythbusting-dont-use-and-or-but-to-start-a-sentence/).